# Connect function with link

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can i connect every link at my page with an `onclick` function.
For example i have :

```
<a href="http://www.something.com">Some text</a>
<a href="http://www.somethingmore.gov">Secret</a>
```

.
I want these links to connect with an onclick function on body load show when i click a link to confirm first.

Comment: you ever tried google?

Comment: @Vivek that is not true. Setting `target` attribute has nothing to do with adding event listeners

Comment: In general, you can [find each anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), loop over them, and [add to each your choice of event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: @Vivek preventing the default action is not what target does

Comment: @Vivek `target` just specifies that the browser should open the anchor's `href` in a particular window (`_blank` meaning a new window). This isn't mutually-exclusive from event binding; the two features can be used together on an anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.querySelectorAll`.This will give a collection of all the `a` tag. Then iterate over it and add event listener. The `test` is a dummy  function, you can replace it with other function

```js
function test() {
  console.log(" Test")

}
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    test();
  })
})
```

```html
<a href="http://www.something.com">Some text</a>
<a href="http://www.somethingmore.gov">Secret</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want these links to connect with an onclick function on body load
>   show when i click a link to confirm first.

You can use `querySelectAll('a')` then iterate through the links and add a generic click event.

To get the user to confirm first, inside the event you could call `confirm()` and if the user does not want to continue you can stop the default behavior of the link using `preventDefault()` to ensure the link does not forward.

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

links.forEach(function(element){
  element.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var isContinue = confirm('Do you want to go to ' + this.href + ' ?');
    
    if(!isContinue){
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<a href="https://www.something.com">Some text</a>
<a href="https://www.somethingmore.gov">Secret</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used onclick function for a tag

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Vote Me";
}
```

```html
<a onclick="myFunction()">Click me</a>

<p id="demo"></p>
```